# Location of zip archive after extracting Excel File

Tags: excel, unzip, vba

We use code to track file usage on Excel workbooks.  Currently we hardcode a server location that is reported back to us when the file is opened and macros are enabled.  If the Excel file is on a SharePoint or on a Network share the following will work

```
Dim Share as String
Dim Text as String
Dim arr() as String

Text = ActiveWorkbook.Path

If Left(Text, 5) = "https" Then
    Share = "SharePoint"
Else
    arr = Split(Text, "\")
    Share = Left((arr(4)), 3) & " Share"
End If

MsgBox Share
```

This will either report back "SharePoint" or the first three characters of the share drive name and the word "Share".  After this we have additional code which completes the tracking process.

Issue is if the Excel is in a zip file the Excel file is temporarily stored in the user profile.  Which renders the above not effective.  Is there any way to determine the location of the zip archive which the Excel file was opened from? Thank you

Comment: you probably need to show the code where you obtain the file not the code to show how you get the path of the workbook.

Comment: I don't think what you're asking is possible to do. A possible workaround though, would be to hardcode the zip file location within the Excel file and track that instead.

Comment: We hardcode the path already.  Or, I should say an identifiable location.  Issue I'm trying to resolve is if I were to share out this code and the path is not hardcoded into the workbook it fails (can put in error code).  Just didn't know if anyone knew of a way to determine the location of the zip archive that opened the Excel file.

Comment: Consider for a moment what it would require to determine where you got some zip file from WITHOUT the path being hardcoded into the file you unzip. You would need a complete log of (zip) file transfers onto the workstation in question and a resident program to monitor when the Excel file in the zip file in question was opened to track with. Only top secure facilities would employ such security measures, and I seriously doubt they do that where you work.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback